# Combo box load with a progress bar

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a combobox, a button. on click of a button I want to load some values(huge datalist or much computed values which will take time to list the data) in to combobox, mean while i wanted to show the progress bar for the load.
How can i achieve this? Can anyone guide me on this?

Regards
Prakas

Comment: This is actually a surprisingly interesting problem, because of the action of populating the combobox necessarily needing to take place on the UI thread. The fetching of the values can happen on a background thread, though. A more elegant solution would be to [use databinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).